# Using actions inside of a controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to ember and I would like to use a separate action (shown as shuffle) in one of my actions(assign). I know I'm doing something wrong here, the shuffle method isn't really doing anything. Am I calling it incorrectly or are actions not supposed to be used by other actions? Here is the code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  taskData: [],
  personData: [],
  taskIn: ' ',
  personIn: ' ',



  actions: {

    saveTask() {

        const task = this.get("taskIn");
        this.taskData.push(task);
    },

    savePerson()
    {
        const person = this.get("personIn");
        this.personData.push(person);
    },

    print(){
        var taskString;

        //this.taskData.remove(0);
        for(var i = 0; i < this.taskData.length; i++)
        {
            taskString = taskString + this.taskData[i];
        }
        alert(taskString);
        //alert(this.personData);
    },

    shuffle(array) {
        var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {

            // Pick a remaining element...
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;

            // And swap it with the current element.
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }

        return array;
    },

    //algorithm to match up tasks with people
    assign(){


        var newTaskD = this.shuffle(this.taskData);
        var newPersonD = this.shuffle(this.personData);
        var taskString = '';
        var peopleString = '';

        for(var i = 0; i<newTaskD.length; i++)
        {
            taskString += " " + newTaskD[i];

        }

        for(var j = 0; j<peopleString.length; j++)
        {
            peopleString += " " + newPersonD[j];

        }

        alert(peopleString);
        alert(taskString);

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Does the interface ever need to be triggering the `shuffle` action? Or are you just trying to set up a method that at least one action needs to call?

Comment: I'm trying to do the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you define your action inside the `actions` hash they are called in the context of the controller. So `this` is the controller, not the action hash.

This is the reason why `this.shuffle` doesn't work: Because `shuffle` is not defined on the controller but on the `actions` hash.

What will do is this:

```
this.actions.shuffle();
```

But then your `this` context of the `shuffle` action would be wrong: It would be the `actions` hash, not the controller. So you would have to override this:

```
this.actions.shuffle.call(this);
```

But this is a bit ugly right? So to answer your question:

> or are actions not supposed to be used by other actions?

Yes! I would recommend *not* to do this, but rather call a normal function inside the same `controller.js` file or use a normal method defined on the controller. So either do this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

function foo(arg) {
  ...
  return something;
}

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    bar() {
      let baz = foo(this.things);
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Or this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

function foo(arg) {
  ...
  return something;
}

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  foo(arg) {
    ...
    return something;
  },
  actions: {
    bar() {
      let baz = this.foo(this.things);
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The Idea about the `actions` hash is to separate between functions called by your template (`actions`)  and normal methods.

Comment: Thanks bro, this helped a lot!

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest after I found out what you were trying to accomplish. Well done. :)